# How do I set cmake output as a dependency to make?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make

Summary:
I am using an open source project which uses 'make' internally. I find it extremely complicated to use, so I want to use 'cmake' for my own code while the existing open source project code remains managed by make.

Problem:
However I can't find any way to invoke my 'cmake' build script from within 'make' and have the 'cmake' output (which is a .so library) as a dependency to the 'make' build.
I read large parts of the manual and looked through many online tutorials on 'make' with no luck.

Further info:
My own code is written in C++ and therefore my 'cmake' script has two branches: Either it creates an executable, or if a variable is set, it creates a library. It will be necessary to pass a command line argument to the 'cmake' script from within 'make'.

I hope you can help!

Comment: Do you want the library to be a prerequisite of a particular `make` target?

Comment: @Beta: the default goal would be fine. I think I may have described it a bit ambiguously. With "dependency", I just mean that my c++ library should be linked with the open src project. That particular thing can be done by just adding it with -lname, but how do I run cmake, and then run the resulting make while the original make of the open src project waits for the library to be built so it can be linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is how to do it. The default target of the makefile will (probably) be the first target, with a rule like this:

```
all: maybe-some-preqs
    do-some-things
```

Change it to this:

```
all: maybe-some-preqs libraryName.so
    do-some-things

libraryName.so:
    command-that-runs-cmake-just-as-if-you-were-doing-it-from-the-command-line
```